# Fourier series: proving that the limit is zero

Tags: fourier-series, dirichlet-convolution, fejer-kernel

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function that satisfies:

$f(t)=\frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ for every $t\in (0,2\pi]$.

Show that:
$\;\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)-(S_n(f))(t)|^2 dt=0$.

We notice that
$\;\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)-(S_n(f))(t)|^2 dt=
\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f(t)-(S_n(f))(t)\|_2^2$.

So it is sufficient to prove that:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f(t)-(S_n(f))(t)\|_2=0$

$(S_n(f))(t)=(D_n*f)(t)$ where $D_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\exp(ikx)$ is Dirichlet Kernel (which is not an approximate identity! Therefore we cannot use the approximation theorem for approximate identities).

I tried to use Dirichlet's theorem but I am not sure, how to apply it here.
I will highly appreciate your guide.

Comment: Please improve your editing, parentheses not paired etc. ..

Comment: Hey @Han de Bruijn, i think now it's fine

Comment: I took the freedom trying to improve some details in the question. You can always do a rollback if you are not satisfied.

Comment: Assuming that $R\rightarrow C$ means mapping to a circle. Is that right?

Comment: $C$ is the field of complex numbers, and the function is from R to C, defined as I wrote above

Comment: Sorry. At the moment, it's beyond my abilities. Never heard of [Fejér](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) before :-(

Comment: It is actually dirichlet kernel and $S_n(f)=D_n*f$

Comment: As far as I can see, you are asking for a proof that the Fourier series of a periodic function converges to that function. There must be a zillion places where you can find such a proof. I have some in my handwritten notes (50 years ago) but I'm not going to post them here, because I'm sure you can find something better elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, function is singular at $t=0$ ..

Comment: Hello @Han de Bruijn do you think that Dirichlet theorem (for fourier series) can be useful hee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a consequence of Plancherel's theorem: Consider $g_n:= f-S_nf$, then up to a constant (depending on your normalization of the Fourier coefficients) we have
$$
\| g_n\|_{L^2}^2= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{g}_n(k)|^2.
$$
Now notice that
$$
\hat{g}_n(k)= 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } & |k|\leq n,\\
\hat{f}(k) & \text{ if } & |k|>n,
\end{cases}
$$
so that
$$
\| g_n\|_{L^2}^2 = \sum_{|k|>n} |\hat{f}_n(k)|^2.
$$
Now since $f\in L^2$ we have $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(k)|^2<\infty$, then the sum in the last display tends to zero as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Hi, thanks , I know that the plancherel formula  connects to fourier transform. You actually did not use it here for fourier series right? ,  Why does $g_n\in L^2$? @Jose27

Comment: @user726608: I used Plancherel's theorem for Fourier series (it's the same, just with sums on the Fourier side instead of integrals). $g_n\in L^2$ since it's the difference of two periodic $L^2$ functions (notice that $S_nf$ being a trigonometric polynomial is actually bounded on $[0,2\pi)$).